# Make Material-UI InputAdornment Icon only visible when selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to make the Material-UI Icon adornment in this sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w385h) only visible when the user selects the text field?

Code:

```
<TextField
  className={classes.margin}
  id="input-with-icon-textfield"
  label="TextField"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>
```

I'm hoping for a clean solution that uses Material-UI props.

Answer (score 6):

Realized the solution right after I posted this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w385h

Set an `IconAdornment` variable to contain our `InputProps` when `isSelected === true`.

`OnFocus`: `setIsSelected(true)` and `OnBlur`:`setIsSelected(false)`.

```
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

  const iconAdornment = isSelected
    ? {
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <AccountCircle />
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }
    : {};

  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.margin}
      id="input-with-icon-textfield"
      label="TextField"
      InputProps={iconAdornment}
      onFocus={e => setIsSelected(true)}
      onBlur={e => setIsSelected(false)}
    />
  );
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you add an `onClick` to `<InputAdornment />`, you won't be able to click it. It loses the focus first, then it hides the element and then you cannot click it anymore :(